# Wireless router country codes: what issues can these actually cause?

Tags: networking, router, wifi

Running the network diagnostics tool on my Mac, I get a messaging about "Conflicting Country Codes" stating that:

> "A nearby wireless router has been detected which is identifying
>   itself as originating from a country which conflicts with your current
>   settings. This may prevent your Mac from automatically re-joining a
>   previously joined Wi-Fi network."

Now, I confess that I didn't realise that Wi-Fi routers had country codes, and this seems like the most stupid and pointless idea I've ever heard of. But, it does raise the following interrelated questions:

- Why would it possibly matter to my Mac that some random router
  somewhere, possibly beyond my control in any case, is configured with
  a such-and-such a country code?
- What actual problem could this cause? Can it really stop my Mac from
  "automatically re-joining" a network for some spurious reason?
- How generally can I query the country code of a given router? (is
  there a standard network diagnostic tool, or does it just depend on
  whether the particular device in question happens to provide this
  info in its configuration interface?)
- And related: given a connectivity issue, what then are the symptoms
  that this is being caused by country codes?

Comment: I don't have time for a longer answer, but the reason routers ask for the country that they are installed in is because there are strict laws with heavy penalties around which channels can be used. If a particular wifi channel overlaps with a countries emergency network frequency, you better damn well not use it.

Comment: OK, so I can sort of see that if there were ambulances whizzing about the landing here on the 5th floor that could be a conundrum, but from the point of view of my computer, why would it think: "I'd better not re-connect to that network because the neighbour's wireless router says it's from Botswana"...?

Comment: For a reason why OSX warns you of that, a much more narrowly scoped question posted on apple.stackexchange.com might yield a better response for you. As for your trivilisation of spectrum laws, your WiFi noise goes further than you think.